# Custom Adapter that chooses to show object or not in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I'm doing a custom adapter and I want it to choose to show the text or not in the list based on some properties of the `Object`. Here is what I'm trying to do:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Array of Objects
    CustomObject[] customObjects = new CustomObject[5];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Creating the array
        customObjects[0] = new CustomObject("Object 0", false, false, true);
        customObjects[1] = new CustomObject("Object 1", true, false, true);
        customObjects[2] = new CustomObject("Object 2", true, false, true);
        customObjects[3] = new CustomObject("Object 3", false, false, true);
        customObjects[4] = new CustomObject("Object 4", true, false, true);

        // Adapter
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, customObjects, "propertyOne");

        // Creating ListView
        ListView listViewItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customList);
        listViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/customList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

**list_layout.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="" />
```

**CustomObject.java:**

```
public class CustomObject {

    private String name;
    private boolean propertyOne;
    private boolean propertyTwo;
    private boolean propertyThree;

    public CustomObject (String name, boolean propertyOne, boolean propertyTwo, boolean propertyThree){
        this.name = name;
        this.propertyOne = propertyOne;
        this.propertyTwo = propertyTwo;
        this.propertyThree = propertyThree;
    }


    public boolean compareProperty(String property) {
        if (property.equals("propertyOne")) {
            return this.propertyOne;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

}
```

**CustomListAapter.java:**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Spells> {

    Context mContext;
    int layoutResourceId;
    CustomObject data[] = null;
    private String property;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, CustomObject[] customObjects, String property){
        super (mContext, layoutResourceId, magias);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.data = customObjects;
        this.property = property;   
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        CustomObject object = data[position];
        if (object.compareProperty(this.property)) {
            TextView textViewItem = (TextView);
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
            textViewItem.setText(object.getName());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Basically, when I send the `String propertyOne`, I want to create a list that shows just the `Objects` that have the `boolean propertyOne` as `true`. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Why not check if they have that property **before** setting the `Adapter`. Then only adding them to the `Adapter` if they have that property?

Comment: what @codeMagic is suggesting you is correct. If you don't want to show an item, you should remove it from the dataset

Comment: Thank you guys, removing it before worked for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

final int LENGTH = 5;

// Array of Objects
CustomObject[] customObjects = new CustomObject[LENGTH];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Creating the array
    customObjects[0] = new CustomObject("Object 0", false, false, true);
    customObjects[1] = new CustomObject("Object 1", true, false, true);
    customObjects[2] = new CustomObject("Object 2", true, false, true);
    customObjects[3] = new CustomObject("Object 3", false, false, true);
    customObjects[4] = new CustomObject("Object 4", true, false, true);

    int newLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        if (customObjects[i].compareProperty("propertyOne")) {
            newLength++;
        }
    }
    CustomObject[] newCustomObjects = new CustomObject[newLength + 1];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        if (customObjects[i].compareProperty("propertyOne")) {
            newCustomObjects[j] = customObjects[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    newCustomObjects[newLength] = new CustomObject (" ", " ", true, true, true)

    //Adapter
    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, newCustomObjects);

    //Creating ListView
    ListView listViewItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customList);
    listViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**CustomListAapter.java:**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Spells> {

    Context mContext;
    int layoutResourceId;
    CustomObject data[] = null;
    private String property;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, CustomObject[] customObjects){
        super (mContext, layoutResourceId, magias);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.data = customObjects; 
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        CustomObject object = data[position];

        TextView textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
        textViewItem.setText(object.getName());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```